# Conservative rendering of the boundary of mandelbrot set

Tags: algorithm, fractals

The mandelbrot set contains points for which the mandelbrot iteration is bounded, the iterated point never "escapes".

Let's define the boundary as points, where the iterated point escapes after *N* iterations (by escape I mean that the distance from the origin becomes larger than 2).

Is it possible to conservatively render the boundary of mandelbrot set? I mean, if a pixel-area covers any point, for which the escape-iteration-count is larger than *N*, then the pixel should be set.

---

Here's some additional explanation what I'm asking: I'd like to handle a pixel as an area, and check all points in that area (infinitely many points) for maximum escape-iteration-count. Like, treat a pixel as a solid square, and apply the mandelbrot iteration to this square (instead of a point). The question is: does any part of this square has an escape-iteration-count larger than *N*?

Comment: I suspect the answer is "no", simply because if it were "yes", there would be an extremely fast technique for rendering: Starting with a "pixel" consisting of the entire bitmap, test the current pixel to see whether any point in it exceeds the maximum iteration count, and if so then recursively subdivide into 4 "subpixels" each of half the height and width.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: that's what I think too. When applying several mandelbrot iterations to a solid square, it most likely becomes something unmanageable (hard-to-describe boundary, self-intersecting, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Sure. That's exactly what every one of the dozens of Mandelbrot renderers you'll find all over the Internet does. Most use different colors to represent the number of iterations before divergence. Those that fail to diverge within some maximum number of iterations are generally shown with black, but of course that's up to the implementer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that you've missed an important detail of my question. Those renderers checks only one point for a pixel. I'd like to handle a pixel as an area, and check all points in that area (infinitely many points) for maximum escape-iteration-count. Like, treat a pixel as a solid square, and apply the mandelbrot iteration to this square (instead of a point). The question is: does any part of this square has an escape-iteration-count larger than *N*?